# Monit and Thin and Unfound Gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, monit, gem, thin

I've been using Monit to monitor my Thin server and everything was working until I upgraded my Rails version from 2.3.4 to 2.3.14.  Now when I try and start Thin using monit it gives me an unfound gem error:

```
Missing the Rails 2.3.14 gem. Please `gem install -v=2.3.14 rails`
```

I thought this may be a GEM PATH issue and also tried setting the GEM_HOME and PATH variables in the start command:

```
check process thin3001
  with pidfile /home/blahblah/apps/Vocab/shared/pids/thin.3001.pid
  start program = "/usr/bin/env PATH=/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems GEM_HOME=/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems /usr/bin/ruby /usr/bin/thin -C /etc/thin/vocab.yml start -o 3001"
  stop program = "/usr/bin/ruby /usr/bin/thin -C /etc/thin/vocab.yml stop -o 3001"
  if totalmem > 150.0 MB for 5 cycles then restart
group thin
```

It's strange because if I run the start command in the console it works fine, it's only within monit that I get the missing Gems error.

Comment: Which rack version are you running `gem list rack`?

Comment: rack (1.1.3, 1.0.0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, came across something about monit not loading the console environment and I guess it was not loading the correct Ruby path or something.  Anyways, got it to work with the following:

`start program = "/bin/su - user -c '/usr/bin/thin -C /etc/thin/vocab.yml start -o 3000'"`

The "/bin/su - user -c" loads the shell environment of user (you need to replace this with your username).

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the latest `rack` doesn't work with the current version of `thin`. Uninstall rack 1.1.3 to see if your problem go away:

```
gem uninstall rack -v=1.1.3
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. Thing is, thin starts fine when I run it in the console.  Also, I get this warning when I go to uninstall, "actionpack-2.3.14 depends on [rack (~> 1.1.0)]."